# Why am I not able to change fill pattern, in Firefox, on a text element using jquery?

Tags: jquery, svg

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/swqg35zk/2/):

```
<pattern id="background-pattern-base" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="640" height="320" >
    <image xlink:href="../private_images/testata-2015/testata-base.jpg" width="640" height="320" />
</pattern>

<pattern id="background-pattern-001" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="640" height="320" >
    <image xlink:href="../private_images/testata-2015/testata-001.jpg" width="640" height="320" />
</pattern>

<text class="item-text" fill="url(#background-pattern-base)" dominant-baseline="text-before-edge">Item 1</text>      
<text class="item-text" fill="url(#background-pattern-base)" dominant-baseline="text-before-edge">Item 2</text>      
<text class="item-text" fill="url(#background-pattern-base)" dominant-baseline="text-before-edge">Item 3</text>      
<text class="item-text" fill="url(#background-pattern-base)" dominant-baseline="text-before-edge">Item 4</text>
```

and I want to switch from `background-pattern-base` to `background-pattern-001` for every `text` element I got:

```
$('.item-text').attr('fill', 'url(#background-pattern-001)');
```

but it works only on Chrome. It fails in Firefox. Where am I wrong?

EDIT: Document opening:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#f1f1ef;">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="container-svg">
                    <svg>
                        <defs>
                            // <patterns>
                        </defs>

                        // <text>
                    </svg>
                </div>                      
            </div>                                      
        </div>                                  
    </form>     
</body>
```

Comment: ... Something is missing here I cannot find any reference to either `<text>`, `<image>`  or `<pattern>` being valid html tags. This may have something to do with it.

Comment: Tested on Firefox 40, in Linux Mint 17.2 Rafael, seems to be working. Do you get any errors?

Comment: No I don't get any errors!

Comment: are you using the xml name space or the HTML5 namespace for your SVG? If the former - you have to add this to your query. Please post your opening SVG element so we can have a look.

Comment: @MichaelMullany: here you go! I've edited the question.

Comment: Here there is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/swqg35zk/2/ . On Firefox it doesnt change pattern. On Chrome yes, without problems. Click on `Change pattern` in the example.

Comment: It's a bug but it's fixed in the [nightlies](https://nightly.mozilla.org/) so just wait for a new release. No need to report it.

Comment: Can I see the link/status of the bug? So I can monitor when it will be released also...

Comment: I've no idea what the bug number is, or even if there is one. I checked the my local trunk build and it works there. There's a tool called mozregression you could use to track down what fixed or broke things. http://mozilla.github.io/mozregression/

Comment: I've got a new update right now, 40.0.3. But the problem is not fixed at all :O